# Is this Power Rule correct?

Tags: statistics, contest-math, education

$\left(\frac{\ 1 }{(1+x)^{1+b}}\right)$ = ${(1+x)^{-(1+b)}}$

where  x and  b are any real numbers

Comment: Yes, as long as the equation is defined (when $x \not= -1$).

Comment: As long as $1+x>0$, to be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There need to be restrictions generally so as for the expression to be legit. First of all, it must be $1+x \neq 0$ since it is the denomimator of a fraction. Secondly, it's a quantity below of a root, so it also must be positive.

I am mentioning these because despite the power rule being correct, the expression wouldn't be legit for any $x$ or $b$ as you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you , yes I did not think about the interval.